# Escape regex special characters in javascript but still retain string integrity for matching keywords

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

Im trying to highlight some text on my web page as the user types in the search box. My search algo is simply matching each space separated keyword. I thought this function was perfect until I started adding brackets to my search term. That kicks up
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: ****: Unterminated group"
as its getting interpreted by the regex. Ive tried to escape the brackets and other characters but then the highlighting isn't working.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOaYEv

```
highlight (str) {
    // this line works but prevents highlighting multiple keywords that arent connected
    // var replacedStr = (this.search || '').replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?.\\^$|#\s,]/g, '\\$&')

    // you can comment this line and uncomment above to see a different but not perfect option
    var replacedStr = (this.search || '').replace(/ /g, '|')
    return str.replace(new RegExp(replacedStr, 'gi'), match => {
      return '<span class="font-weight-bold">' + match + '</span>'
    })
}
```

So i need to escape the brackets. Which ive tried in the commented line but then the function fails to highlight all keywords in the text :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape each non-whitespace chunk you want to search for and highlight. Also, there is no need to use a callback inside `replace` to replace with a whole match, you may use a `$&` backreference.

See the [updated JS](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLMVNG):

```
vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            search: null,
            message: 'Search this text for matches (check the bracketed area too)'
        };
    },
    computed: {},
    methods: {
        highlight (str) {
          var replacedStr = (this.search || '').trim().split(/\s+/).map(x => x.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?.\\^$|#\s,]/g, '\\$&')).join("|");
          return str.replace(new RegExp(replacedStr, 'gi'), 
            '<span class="teal--text text--darken-1 font-weight-bold">$&</span>');
        }
    }
});
```

Here:

- `.trim().split(/\s+/).map(x => x.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?.\\^$|#\s,]/g, '\\$&')).join("|")` - trims the input string with `trim()`, then splits out all non-whitespace chunks with `.split(/\s+/)`, then these chunks are escaped with `.map(x => x.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?.\\^$|#\s,]/g, '\\$&'))`, and then `.join("|")` creates a regex pattern with a list of alternatives.
- In the `'<span class="teal--text text--darken-1 font-weight-bold">$&</span>'` string replacement pattern, the `$&` parts stands for the whole match value.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Great explanation of how it works too. Thanks Wiktor!